# How to further reduce Angular 7 build size, when all modules are already being lazy loaded?

Tags: angular, angular7

My initial production build size of main.js was 1.5M. Clearly unacceptable, the cold start loading time was around 17 seconds. So I checked some online sources on how to tackle this, and employed lazy loading of modules. That reduced the main.js to 541kB. An improvement to be sure, but I'd like to squeeze it further, possibly down to 200 or so kB. I start the build process by using `npm run build` (I am primarily a java dev, so I don't know if this is the right way), which in turn calls `ng build --prod`. Now here come the questions:

Does the --prod flag include all the optimizations I could possibly want? Or should I enable more of them explicitly by using more command options. The official [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build) on this is not very clear to me. Specifically, it says :

> When true, sets the build configuration to the production target. All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking. A production build also runs limited dead code elimination.

Why only limited? Don't I want the full tree shaking and dead code elimination? Are there any other flags besides `--prod` I should know of? It appears that options such as `--buildOptimizer` and others are set to true in `angular.json` for prod builds, so it seems I can't get any more benefits by tweaking the build process. AOT, uglification, etc. should also be used by default.

What other techniques could I possibly use? I could of course use gzip on my server, but that is outside of the scope of angular itself. I find it hard to believe that my simple app could be that large, I am probably missing something.

Comment: Upgrade to angular 8 :) It uses differential loading - smaller bundle sizes for evergreen browsers.

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis It's not out yet, is it? I checked yesterday, it should supposedly have Ivy and make builds much smaller, but the latest stable version is 7.2.5, I think.

Comment: No 8 was released. I upgraded today :)

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis upgrading now. How do I make the proper use of this differential loading? Is it automatic, or does it have to be enabled somehow?

Comment: https://dev.to/lacolaco/differential-loading-a-new-feature-of-angular-cli-v8-4jl

Answer (score 1):

541kB is peanuts.

As you have said, you have several flags in the `angular.json` files that are enabled when using the `--prod` flag. By default, that would be

```
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [{
            "type": "initial",
            "maximumWarning": "2mb",
            "maximumError": "5mb"
          }]
```

[You can find all the possible flags here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

In the end, if you want to further reduce the size of your main script, you will have to do it by hand : Angular optimization can go so far, the rest depends on how you code.

For instance, factorizing your code, removing the unused code, reusing common components, reducing the size of the initial module, reduce the amount of repeated HTML & CSS ... It all comes down to how many letters are in your file, so the fewer letters you have, the lighter the main script will be.

Finally, somme techniques are available to you to further increase the performance for the first rendering of your application, such as [service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) or [server-side rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

Comment: I am aware that some angular apps can potentially go up to tens of megabytes, but my app is fairly simple and I suspect there should be no reason for it to be even "peanuts" sized :) I'll check out your recommendations and see where it gets me, thanks.